# Using scanf on integer

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

My task is to create array, In order to do that I need to input size, but I have to make sure that the input isn't negative, letter or symbol. I created function to do that, but my if doesn't work properly. If I enter negative number or character it still uses it.

Here's the function which I use:

```
void getsize(int* size){
    printf("Enter the size of array\n");
  if ((scanf("%d", size) == 1) && (getchar() == '\n') && (size > 0)){
     printf("Size: %d entered\n", *size);
  } else {
   printf("wrong input\n");
   while(getchar() != '\n');
  }
}

getsize(&size);
```

Comment: `"%d"` wouldn't obtain non-digit characters anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is, you compare the address of the value to 0. `size` is a pointer, so use:

```
 (*size > 0)
```

instead of

```
 (size > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the pointer with the `0`, not the value you've stored inside the memory location it points to. Inside your `if`, rather use the following as your final comparison:

```
... (*size > 0)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

in your if statement.  you are checking for `size > 0`
This should be `*size > 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
void getsize(int* size){
    printf("Enter the size of array\n");
    if ((scanf_s("%d", size) == 1) && (getchar() == '\n') && (*size > 0)){
        printf("Size: %d entered\n", *size);
    }
    else {
        printf("wrong input\n");
        while (getchar() != '\n');
    }
}
```

This works for me. Just change size>0 to *size>0, because you must check the value, not the address.